# UnauthorizedAccessException Writing to File using Cortana's Universal Windows Service

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm creating a Cortanta app (A universal windows app with a service launched within the app). But I'm running into an error. I'm still learning how eactly this all works.

But here's the error I get:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Access to the path 'C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Roaming' is denied.
  Source=System.IO.FileSystem
```

I'm using a TextWriter as I would normally in a regular desktop app. The service lacks the permissions needed to write to a file.

Is there a way I can use code to elevate the service to write to where I need to? Would I add this to the parent universal windows app (Cortana app) or need to do this within the service project itself?

Code to write:

```
 using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JOHN\\AppData\\Roaming\\APPTEST\\IPC_File.s"))
                            {
                               writer.WriteLine(voicecommand.SpeechRecognitionResult.Text.ToString());
                            }
```

I tried temporarily giving 'Everyone' access to the APPTEST folder, but it changed nothing.

**Or is there some way I can find out what the windows service has access to write to?** I think I can change my desktop app to look for files in that location if needed if my approach isn't working.

Comment: You shouldn't try to access roaming folders directly, instead you should use storage api, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx

Comment: If I'm trying to communicate with a desktop app by method of writing to a file, will storage api still work? Is there a way for the desktop app to know what storage location my universal service/app used?

Comment: yes you can use the same storage api for desktop apps as well

Answer (score 2):

UWP app was running in an app container (a low integrity process), this process does not has the full access to Roaming folder. By default, it has the access to app data package folder “C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Packages{Package family name}”.

It is a little difficult for the external process to access this folder without knowing the package family name. You can get it from the Visual Studio Packaging properties.
[image]

**UWP App**

```
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        var path = localFolder.Path;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(path, "IPC_File.s")))
            {
                writer.Write("Hello World");
            }
        });
```

**External .NET Desktop App**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Packages\[PACKAGE_FAMILY_ID]\LocalState\IPC_File.s");
    }
```